# Question related to Poisson process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, poisson-process

Suppose busses arrive at a bus stop either with an inter-arrival time of exactly 1 min or with an inter-arrival time of exactly 10 mins. Suppose the 1 min inter-arrival times occur with probability 2/3 and the 10 min inter-arrival times occur with probability 1/3. What is the average inter-arrival time between bus arrivals?  .What is the probability that a person, arriving uniformly at random, lands in the 10 min inter-arrival time?

Answers to questions are 4 and 5/6 respectively.

For the first one I tried solving it this way: either it is 10 min interval or 1 min interval so multiplied each one with their probabilities, adding them up and then taking reciprocal (as the average in exponential is 1/lambda). But that seems to be wrong. And for secondly I have no clue

Comment: After $3n$ busses passed, if $n$ is large, by the LLN, roughly $2n$ corresponded to 1 min inter-arrival times and $n$ to 10 min inter-arrival times, hence the mean inter-arrival time is roughly $(2n\cdot1+n\cdot10)/(3n)=4$. Likewise, after $3n$ busses passed, if $n$ is large, by the LLN, roughly $12n$ min passed, during which roughly $2n$ minutes corresponded to 1 min inter-arrival times, and roughly $10n$ minutes corresponded to 10 min inter-arrival times, thus the probability of a 10 min interval is roughly $10n/(12n)=5/6$.

Comment: I dont understand your intuition. Can you please rephrase it

Comment: @Did  I dont understand your intuition. Can you please rephrase it

Comment: I dont understand what you fail to get in the precise proof (not intuition, thanks) in my first comment. Can you please phrase what you are missing here?